Intel Arc Graphics GPU not detected by Python (TensorFlow)
I'm having trouble getting my Intel Arc Graphics GPU recognized by Python (specifically, TensorFlow). I've installed the latest drivers and TensorFlow version, but when I run
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
it only detects my CPU.
I tried:

Installing the latest Intel Arc Graphics drivers
Installing the latest TensorFlow version (2.9.1)
Setting environment variables like TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS and TF_XLA_FLAGS
Running tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') to detect the GPU.

I was expecting to see my Intel Arc Graphics GPU listed as a available device when running
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
but it's not detected. I'm expecting to be able to use my GPU for TensorFlow computations, but it's not being recognized. Has anyone successfully gotten their Intel Arc Graphics GPU working with TensorFlow on Windows 11? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

TensorFlow does not support Intel ARC GPUs out of the box, you probably did not install the correct versions. Also the latest version of TensorFlow is not 2.9, you should clarify exactly what packages were installed and from where.

You can use the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin package, which uses Tensorflow's PluggableDevice architecture to create a DirectML backend.
The package can be directly installed with pip:
pip install tensorflow-directml-plugin

Or may be built from source via the package's github repository.
The package requires the GPU to be compatible with DirectX 12, though this should not be a problem for you given the Intel GPU you have listed.
Note that the package runs using tensorflow-cpu, not tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu, though this dependency will be resolved upon installation.
